# Javascript browser notification not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show notification to the users if the browser is not Chrome.

What I did till now is

the **div** to show when if browser is other than chrome:

```
<div id="notify"> Please use chrome browser </div>
```

the **CSS**:

```
#notify{
  display:none;
}
```

and the **Javascript** as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/2675010):

```
<script>
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;
            if(isChrome==false)  //if the browser is not chrome
            {
                alert("Please Use chrome browser");   // this works
                document.getElementById('notify').show();  //this doesn't work
            }
</script>
```

the script is place above the div tag.
What is wrong with the second statment?

Comment: **`please use chrome browser console`**

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want someone to use chrome on your site/webapp? Browser detection should really only be done there is no other possibility. The problem is that on the one hand someone could change the user-agent name, and even the vendor could change it with a new version (like MS did with IE 11)

Comment: Your script must be located AFTER the div tag or you must wait until the page is loaded before running it.

Comment: @t.niese Yes. some animations of my app work only in chrome!

Comment: @whoIsCraig Then a better way would be to detect the browser features, and if the animation does not work, then display the warning. If you e.g. use css keyframes for you animations with the `webkit` vendor prefix for it, then it would most likely also run in latest Safari, Opera, Chromium or any other browser based on WebKit or Blink and not just only in Chrome.

Comment: If you put your code on a js fiddle and describe what you are trying to do/achieve, maybe peolple can help you improve it to work across other platforms other than just chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`show` is not a native method of Javascript. If you are using jQuery, the correct syntax would be

`$('#notify').show()`

if you are using vanilla javascript you should use:

`document.getElementById('notify').style.display = 'block';`

Also put the `script` below the `div` tag.

Comment: For plain JS, better to use `document.getElementById('notify').style.display = "block";` and not overwrite other style values that might be set.

Comment: @whoIsCraig - you also must put the script AFTER the div tag.

Comment: @jfriend00 that was the culprit!!

Answer (score 1):

Please don't mix up Jquery's .show() function with JavaScript's selector. Please read this for full reference, [Jquery ID selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Instead of this,

```
document.getElementById('notify').show();
```

Use this,

```
$('#notify').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
document.getElementById('notify').style.display='block';
```

instead of ,

```
document.getElementById('notify').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#notify").show()
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('notify').show();
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wLsVk/)

Answer (score 0):

If you really must do such a thing, change the content of the document instead of just styling (which will be ignored in some situations). And manipulating an element, is possible only after the element has been parsed. Example:

```
<div id="notify"></div>
<script>
if(!window.chrome || isOpera) {
   document.getElementById('notify').innerHTML =
      'Please use the Chrome browser.';
}
</script>
```